# File sharing through ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a web application where different users (online users) may share files with each other. I don't know how to implement this module, mean what should I study and search. It should be similar as we share files at FaceBook. I am working in ASP.NET/C#.
Any help, code etc will be appreciated. I have searched on Google but all results lead to
file sharing softwares which are not helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: I liked it I think [this link](http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-explorer-browser/online-share/web-file-manager.aspx "Web File Manager") can be useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Gallery_Server_Pro.aspx) could you be good starting point. Not only the tutorial is very descriptive but also you can download the complete source code.

Comment: I already have checked this but it doesn't work for file sharing.